# Select one Secteur and then get all groupements belong to the Secteur in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

The line  `$groupement[] = null === $secteurs ? null : $secteurs->getSecteurid();` 
in the Eleveurtype.php is not working Please i need Some help
The work i wanted to do is to select one Secteur and then i want to get all groupements belong to the Secteur

**This is The EleveurType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('secteurid',EntityType::class, [
            'label'=>'Nom du secteur :',
            'class'  => Secteurs::class,
            'choice_label' => 'secteurfr',
            'attr'=>[
                'class'=>'form-control',
            ] 
        ])
    ;

    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Secteurs $secteurs = null) {
        //$secteurs = null === $secteurs ? [] : $secteurs->getSecteurid();
        $groupement[] = null === $secteurs ? null : $secteurs->getSecteurid();
        $form->add('groupementid', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Groupements::class,
            'placeholder' => '',
            'choices' => $groupement,
            'attr'=>[
                'class'=>'form-control',
            ]
        ]);
    };
    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
            $data = $event->getData();

            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getSecteurid());
        }
    );
    $builder->get('secteurid')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
            // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
            $secteur = $event->getForm()->getData();

            // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
            // the parent to the callback functions!
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $secteur);
        }
    );

}
```

**This is The _form.html.twig Eleveur**

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'newform', 'nam': nam } }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}


    <button type="button" class="{{ classBtnAddEdit|default('btn btnAED btn-success waves-effect waves-light m-1') }} " id="btnAddEdit"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Enregistrer</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
<script>
    var $secteur = $('#eleveurs_secteurid');
    // When sport gets selected ...
    $secteur.change(function() {
        // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        // Simulate form data, but only include the selected sport value.
        var data = {};
        data[$secteur.attr('name')] = $secteur.val();
        // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
        $.ajax({
            url : $form.attr('nam'), //= $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data : data,
            success: function(html) {
                // Replace current position field ...
                $('#eleveurs_groupementid').replaceWith(
                    // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
                    $(html).find('#eleveurs_groupementid')
                );
                // Position field now displays the appropriate positions.
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

** this is the Eleveur Class Eleveur **

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Eleveurs
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="eleveurs", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_relationship_47", columns={"groupementid"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_relationship_53", columns={"douarid"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_relationship_16", columns={"secteurid"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_relationship_49", columns={"villeid"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Eleveurs
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="eleveurid", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $eleveurid;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="codeeleveur", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $codeeleveur;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numcin", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $numcin;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="datecin", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $datecin;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="validitecin", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $validitecin;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nomfr", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nomfr;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prenomfr", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $prenomfr;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nomar", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nomar;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prenomar", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $prenomar;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateadhesion", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateadhesion;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adressefr", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $adressefr;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adressear", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $adressear;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="effectifovin", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $effectifovin;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="effectifcaprin", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $effectifcaprin;

    /**
     * @var \Secteurs
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Secteurs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="secteurid", referencedColumnName="secteurid")
     * })
     */
    private $secteurid;

    /**
     * @var \Groupements
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Groupements")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="groupementid", referencedColumnName="groupementid")
     * })
     */
    private $groupementid;

    /**
     * @var \Villes
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Villes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="villeid", referencedColumnName="villeid")
     * })
     */
    private $villeid;

    /**
     * @var \Douars
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Douars")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="douarid", referencedColumnName="douarid")
     * })
     */
    private $douarid;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Conseilgroupement", mappedBy="eleveurid")
     */
    private $conseilgroupementid;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Droitfonctionement", inversedBy="eleveurid")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="relationship_32",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="eleveurid", referencedColumnName="eleveurid")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="droitfonctionementid", referencedColumnName="droitfonctionementid")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $droitfonctionementid;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Conseilanoc", mappedBy="eleveurid")
     */
    private $conseilanocid;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Superviseurs", mappedBy="eleveurid")
     */
    private $histosuperviseurid;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conseilgroupementid = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->droitfonctionementid = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->conseilanocid = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->histosuperviseurid = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getEleveurid(): ?int
    {
        return $this->eleveurid;
    }

    public function getCodeeleveur(): ?string
    {
        return $this->codeeleveur;
    }

    public function setCodeeleveur(?string $codeeleveur): self
    {
        $this->codeeleveur = $codeeleveur;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNumcin(): ?string
    {
        return $this->numcin;
    }

    public function setNumcin(?string $numcin): self
    {
        $this->numcin = $numcin;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDatecin(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->datecin;
    }

    public function setDatecin(?\DateTimeInterface $datecin): self
    {
        $this->datecin = $datecin;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getValiditecin(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->validitecin;
    }

    public function setValiditecin(?\DateTimeInterface $validitecin): self
    {
        $this->validitecin = $validitecin;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNomfr(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nomfr;
    }

    public function setNomfr(?string $nomfr): self
    {
        $this->nomfr = $nomfr;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrenomfr(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prenomfr;
    }

    public function setPrenomfr(?string $prenomfr): self
    {
        $this->prenomfr = $prenomfr;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNomar(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nomar;
    }

    public function setNomar(?string $nomar): self
    {
        $this->nomar = $nomar;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrenomar(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prenomar;
    }

    public function setPrenomar(?string $prenomar): self
    {
        $this->prenomar = $prenomar;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateadhesion(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateadhesion;
    }

    public function setDateadhesion(?\DateTimeInterface $dateadhesion): self
    {
        $this->dateadhesion = $dateadhesion;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdressefr(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adressefr;
    }

    public function setAdressefr(?string $adressefr): self
    {
        $this->adressefr = $adressefr;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdressear(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adressear;
    }

    public function setAdressear(?string $adressear): self
    {
        $this->adressear = $adressear;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEffectifovin(): ?int
    {
        return $this->effectifovin;
    }

    public function setEffectifovin(?int $effectifovin): self
    {
        $this->effectifovin = $effectifovin;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEffectifcaprin(): ?int
    {
        return $this->effectifcaprin;
    }

    public function setEffectifcaprin(?int $effectifcaprin): self
    {
        $this->effectifcaprin = $effectifcaprin;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSecteurid(): ?Secteurs
    {
        return $this->secteurid;
    }

    public function setSecteurid(?Secteurs $secteurid): self
    {
        $this->secteurid = $secteurid;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGroupementid(): ?Groupements
    {
        return $this->groupementid;
    }

    public function setGroupementid(?Groupements $groupementid): self
    {
        $this->groupementid = $groupementid;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVilleid(): ?Villes
    {
        return $this->villeid;
    }

    public function setVilleid(?Villes $villeid): self
    {
        $this->villeid = $villeid;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDouarid(): ?Douars
    {
        return $this->douarid;
    }

    public function setDouarid(?Douars $douarid): self
    {
        $this->douarid = $douarid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Conseilgroupement[]
     */
    public function getConseilgroupementid(): Collection
    {
        return $this->conseilgroupementid;
    }

    public function addConseilgroupementid(Conseilgroupement $conseilgroupementid): self
    {
        if (!$this->conseilgroupementid->contains($conseilgroupementid)) {
            $this->conseilgroupementid[] = $conseilgroupementid;
            $conseilgroupementid->addEleveurid($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeConseilgroupementid(Conseilgroupement $conseilgroupementid): self
    {
        if ($this->conseilgroupementid->contains($conseilgroupementid)) {
            $this->conseilgroupementid->removeElement($conseilgroupementid);
            $conseilgroupementid->removeEleveurid($this);
        <
```

** This is the Secteur class **

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Secteurs
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="secteurs")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Secteurs
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="secteurid", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $secteurid;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="secteurfr", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $secteurfr;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="secteurar", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $secteurar;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="codesecteur", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $codesecteur;

    public function getSecteurid(): ?int
    {
        return $this->secteurid;
    }

    public function getSecteurfr(): ?string
    {
        return $this->secteurfr;
    }

    public function setSecteurfr(?string $secteurfr): self
    {
        $this->secteurfr = ucfirst($secteurfr);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSecteurar(): ?string
    {
        return $this->secteurar;
    }

    public function setSecteurar(?string $secteurar): self
    {
        $this->secteurar = $secteurar;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCodesecteur(): ?string
    {
        return $this->codesecteur;
    }

    public function setCodesecteur(?string $codesecteur): self
    {
        $this->codesecteur = strtoupper($codesecteur);

        return $this;
    }


}
```

** this is the groupement class **

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Groupements
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="groupements", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_relationship_54", columns={"secteurid"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Groupements
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="groupementid", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $groupementid;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="groupementmereid", type="decimal", precision=8, scale=0, nullable=true)
     */
    private $groupementmereid;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="codegroupement", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $codegroupement;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nomgroupementfr", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nomgroupementfr;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nomgroupementar", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nomgroupementar;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adressepostale", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $adressepostale;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="datecreation", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $datecreation;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pvcreation", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $pvcreation;

    /**
     * @var float|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="droitfonctionement", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=true)
     */
    private $droitfonctionement;

    /**
     * @var float|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="autrecotisations", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=true)
     */
    private $autrecotisations;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="effectifovinencadre", type="decimal", precision=8, scale=0, nullable=true)
     */
    private $effectifovinencadre;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="effectifcaprinencadre", type="decimal", precision=8, scale=0, nullable=true)
     */
    private $effectifcaprinencadre;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lieupvcreation", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $lieupvcreation;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="datepvcreation", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $datepvcreation;

    /**
     * @var \Secteurs
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Secteurs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="secteurid", referencedColumnName="secteurid")
     * })
     */
    private $secteurid;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Droitfonctionement", inversedBy="groupementid")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="relationship_31",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="groupementid", referencedColumnName="groupementid")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="droitfonctionementid", referencedColumnName="droitfonctionementid")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $droitfonctionementid;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->droitfonctionementid = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getGroupementid(): ?int
    {
        return $this->groupementid;
    }

    public function getGroupementmereid(): ?string
    {
        return $this->groupementmereid;
    }

    public function setGroupementmereid(?string $groupementmereid): self
    {
        $this->groupementmereid = $groupementmereid;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCodegroupement(): ?string
    {
        return $this->codegroupement;
    }

    public function setCodegroupement(?string $codegroupement): self
    {
        $this->codegroupement = $codegroupement;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNomgroupementfr(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nomgroupementfr;
    }

    public function setNomgroupementfr(?string $nomgroupementfr): self
    {
        $this->nomgroupementfr = $nomgroupementfr;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNomgroupementar(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nomgroupementar;
    }

    public function setNomgroupementar(?string $nomgroupementar): self
    {
        $this->nomgroupementar = $nomgroupementar;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdressepostale(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adressepostale;
    }

    public function setAdressepostale(?string $adressepostale): self
    {
        $this->adressepostale = $adressepostale;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDatecreation(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->datecreation;
    }

    public function setDatecreation(?\DateTimeInterface $datecreation): self
    {
        $this->datecreation = $datecreation;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPvcreation(): ?string
    {
        return $this->pvcreation;
    }

    public function setPvcreation(?string $pvcreation): self
    {
        $this->pvcreation = $pvcreation;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDroitfonctionement(): ?float
    {
        return $this->droitfonctionement;
    }

    public function setDroitfonctionement(?float $droitfonctionement): self
    {
        $this->droitfonctionement = $droitfonctionement;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAutrecotisations(): ?float
    {
        return $this->autrecotisations;
    }

    public function setAutrecotisations(?float $autrecotisations): self
    {
        $this->autrecotisations = $autrecotisations;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEffectifovinencadre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->effectifovinencadre;
    }

    public function setEffectifovinencadre(?string $effectifovinencadre): self
    {
        $this->effectifovinencadre = $effectifovinencadre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEffectifcaprinencadre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->effectifcaprinencadre;
    }

    public function setEffectifcaprinencadre(?string $effectifcaprinencadre): self
    {
        $this->effectifcaprinencadre = $effectifcaprinencadre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLieupvcreation(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lieupvcreation;
    }

    public function setLieupvcreation(?string $lieupvcreation): self
    {
        $this->lieupvcreation = $lieupvcreation;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDatepvcreation(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->datepvcreation;
    }

    public function setDatepvcreation(?\DateTimeInterface $datepvcreation): self
    {
        $this->datepvcreation = $datepvcreation;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSecteurid(): ?Secteurs
    {
        return $this->secteurid;
    }

    public function setSecteurid(?Secteurs $secteurid): self
    {
        $this->secteurid = $secteurid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Droitfonctionement[]
     */
    public function getDroitfonctionementid(): Collection
    {
        return $this->droitfonctionementid;
    }

    public function addDroitfonctionementid(Droitfonctionement $droitfonctionementid): self
    {
        if (!$this->droitfonctionementid->contains($droitfonctionementid)) {
            $this->droitfonctionementid[] = $droitfonctionementid;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeDroitfonctionementid(Droitfonctionement $droitfonctionementid): self
    {
        if ($this->droitfonctionementid->contains($droitfonctionementid)) {
            $this->droitfonctionementid->removeElement($droitfonctionementid);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to reduce the amont of code ? (in your entities we just need the members as the methods are auto-generated). Also use indent in your `html` this way your question will be shorter and clearer